# jquery hover mouse out

Tags: jquery, hover

I want a simple slide down / up animation on a mouse over of a link. I can get the mouse over to work but I can't work out how to get the mouseout to do it's thing.

Here's what I have for the hover effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("jquery", "1.3.2"); //load version 1.3.2 of jQuery

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    jQuery(
        function($) {
            $("a.button").hover(function(){$(this).animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, "fast")   

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

How do I get this to move the margin up 16px when mouse out?

Comment: the code in the example is not valid! Perhaps you're missing the second function for `.hover(func, func)`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The hover event in jQuery needs 2 callback functions: one when the pointer moves over the item, and one when it leaves:

```
$(item).hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });
```

In your case:

```
$("a.button").hover(
   function() {
      $(this).animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, "fast");
   },
   function() {
      $(this).animate({"marginTop": "16px"}, "fast");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 21):

In newer versions of jQuery (>=1.7) you can also take this approach:

```
$("a.button").on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, "fast");
});
$("a.button").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).animate({"marginTop": "16px"}, "fast");
});
```

In my opinion this is a cleaner approach, and it also takes advantage of the the new .on() function ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution:

```
$("a.button").hover(function() {
  $("a.button").css("cursor","pointer");
});
```