# jQuery mouseover not working as intended

Tags: jquery, mouseover

This is the html I have:

```
<div id="social">
    <a href="#" class="twitter"><span class="text">Twitter</span></a>
</div>
```

What I intend to do is initially hide the span.text and when I hover over the image in the background of the div. This is my css

```
#social a {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:4px 0 0 28px;
/* left padding is for the bg image to be visible*/
}
#social a span {
    display:none;
}
#social .twitter {
    background:url(../images/social/twitter.png) no-repeat left top;
}
#social .twitter:hover {
    background:url(../images/social/twitter_hover.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

And this is my js:

```
$("#social a.twitter").mouseover(function(){
  $("span",this).show("slow");
}).mouseout(function(){
  $("span",this).hide("slow");
});
```

But what happens is when I hover over the image it keeps on showing and hiding the text.. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use .hover instead of .mouseover event. Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116361/jquery-hover-mouse-out

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Nothing wrong with using `mouseover` and `mouseout` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a very common problem, when the span shows, the mouse its not any more over the a, so the mouseout event gets called.

to fix this use mouseenter and mouseleave events

```
$("#social a.twitter").mouseenter(function(){
  $("span",this).show("slow");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $("span",this).hide("slow");
});​
```

[fiddle for you :D](http://jsfiddle.net/hUfbA/)

and, in css the comments are with `/* */` and not with `//`

Comment: Awseome! Works as intended... Another lesson learnt :) Thanks

Comment: you are welcome. it was a couple of headaches until i found it. id suggest that you read the documentation on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: Just one more question... The solution works fine but when I hover over the image the text shows up instantaneously. The hide function slides the text to the bottom corner but not the mouseenter function. How can I make the mouseenter function to slide in the text as well?

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
// left padding is for the bg image to be visible
```

`//` is not a valid symbol for comments.

They have to be wrapped in `/* */` like:

```
/* left padding is for the bg image to be visible */
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I added that comment for this post only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) use javascript for this effect. You can do it with CSS, which is cleaner and more semantic :). Example:

```
​a.twitter {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://www.simplyzesty.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/twitter_newbird_boxed_whiteonblue2.png');
}

a.twitter span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

a.twitter:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ut4Gx/

Comment: Im sorry I think I didn't explain myself clearly. Initially only the twitter icon will b e visible and when you hover, I want the text to slide in, i.e. the icon should move to the left revelaing the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/). Re mouseout:

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves out of the Inner element in
>   this example, a mouseout event will be sent to that, then trickle up
>   to Outer. This can trigger the bound mouseout handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for .mouseleave() for a useful alternative.