# Animation repeating while hovering on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I've read other questions and answers about this issue but they didn't work for me, maybe I am missing something or my example is slightly different, I don't know. Anyway, I have a div with some text and a link inside and I would like to create a new div when the user hovers over this first div. The problem is that, when I am over the first div, the second one fades in and out continuously, even if I don't leave the first div with the mouse.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <div id="web">
            <p>Web apps</p>
            <a href="#">
                First link
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="commentweb">
            <p>The text that I want to show</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#web").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
});

$("#commentweb").hide();

$("#web").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children("a").children("img").attr("src","2.png");
    $(this).css("background-color","#ecf5fb");
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
    $(this).css('border','1px solid #378ac4');
    $(this).children("p").css("opacity","1.0");
    $('#commentweb').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).children("a").children("img").attr("src","1.png");
    $(this).children("p").css("opacity","0.5");
    $(this).css("background-color","#e8e3e3");
    $(this).css('border','1px solid grey');
    $('#commentweb').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
);
});
```

What should I do to have the fade in animation start when I am over #web and the fade out animation when I leave that div, without flickering (i.e. constant fadeIn and fadeOut)?

I have added a fiddle to show you the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mMB3F/
It basically happens when I hover on the text.

Comment: Gee. You gotta lot of `$(this)` in *there*. Why not `var $self = $(this)` and then use `$self`? And use `$self.css({cursor:'pointer', border:'...', ...})` as well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - or just chain all those methods to one selector expression ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will chain the css commands then.

Comment: @adeneo - I don't know it can all be chained. IMO, using a local and some chaining where necessary is better than inexpressive chaining for chaining's sake.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for the interested - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/3uywF/ . @user1301428 I'm not able to see the flickering you mention.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/gYnNG/ (Fade in when I'm on that div , when I'm out of that div - fades out)

Comment: Ooh, here's my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sKjtK/) with some chaining and no flicker there either ??

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have edited my question adding my own fiddle, in which I have added the CSS. It looks like the problem might be there.

Comment: Still , it works. When I over the div , I see that text , when I'm out It fades out.

Comment: @OfirBaruch It works, but if you move the mouse over <p>Web apps</p> the effect breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because your comment div is inside the div that you are assigning the hover event. Note that the flickring occurs when you enter the mouse pointer in the highlighted area (red) showed in the image below (related to the comment div).

[image]

Take a look in this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/mMB3F/1/

The comment div has now a absolute positioning. When the mouse enters, the comment div will be showed next to the pointer. Off course, now you will need to change the code to fit your needs. Another way of doing this is to set an div container that encloses the #web div and to put another div next to it, seting them to float. Inside the new div you insert the div with the comment.

Comment: What you posted works, however I don't understand why you had to change the jQuery code, could you please explain that?

Comment: @user1301428: I changed it just to repositionate the comment div using the mouse pointer coordinates. You can set its position to a static value too changing the `.comment` class in css, using `left` and `top` properties.

Comment: Thanks, but can you also tell me why it doesn't work if I paste my jQuery code in your example? It works only if I leave your jQuery code.

Comment: Also, the comment div is not inside the div I am assigning the hover event to, #commentweb is a sibling of #web, like you said at the beginning of your answer. Did you mean that the problem is that they both are inside the #content div?

Comment: @user1301428: It does not work because it need to be changed. My code is your code with some modifications.

Comment: What about the other question?

Comment: @user1301428: About the #comment div inside the #web div? The way the code is write It does not matter, since #comment is using absolute position and we are dealing with the divs using their id, but I think that putting it outside the #web div makes more sense, since now it is a div that can be positioned in any size of the document. I forgot to put a z-index property in the .comment class. It would be good to put it, so the #comment div will be in some layers above the document content.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

My other answer was a little too grandiose, You just have to float your other div

```
#commentweb {float:left}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mMB3F/5/

<strike>It needs to be asynchronous, the stop() is what causes it to blink, but you dont need a stop if you just wait for the fade to complete before you assign the event handlers.</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/u7Q9P/1/

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` to avoid that.
that way, you dont have to reposition anything in your css.

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130734/jquery-mouseover-not-working-as-intended/11130789#11130789) for more detail

Comment: I have tried that too, but the problem remains. You can see the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mMB3F/4/