# Pause scrollTop on hover

Tags: jquery

Still somewhat new at jQuery, I am using the following to automatically scroll a div with the class name of .scroller when the page loads.

```
$(".scroller").delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: $('.scroller')[0].scrollHeight}, 50000);
```

However I would like to stop any scrolling upon hover over that div and start it back when hovering out.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this or should I be using something other than scrollTop for this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop the animation under condition, you can use : `$(".scroller").stop()`

Then, restart the scrolling as you did without the delay.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$("#myDiv").hover(
    function(){
        $(".scroller").stop();
    },
    function(){
        $(".scroller").animate({ scrollTop: $('.scroller')[0].scrollHeight}, 50000);
    }
);
```

Comment: Excellent, thats it!  I used your code and this post to figure out how to best toggle it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116361/jquery-hover-mouse-out.  Thanks!

Comment: Mean to say, I used your $(".scroller").stop() before you posted the longer code, but used the link to figure it out.  Thanks!